# MVC 4 bundleconfig.cs files not including in layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

BundleConfig.cs

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/resources/css").Include("~/resources/css/reset.css", 
            "~/resources/css/style.css", "~/resources/css/invalid.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/resources/scripts").Include("~/resources/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js",

            "~/resources/scripts/simpla.jquery.configuration.js", "~/resources/scripts/facebox.js",
            "~/resources/scripts/jquery.wysiwyg.js"));
    }
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
 @Styles.Render("~/resources/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/resources/scripts")
```

What it renders in html

```
 <link href="/resources/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/resources/scripts"></script>
```

Not including css and js file paths in html ??

Comment: Bundle paths shouldn't match an existing file system path. Try `new StyleBundle("~/thegreatestbundleofall")` temporarily to see if that changes anything. If it does, come up with a meaningful/functional bundle path (that doesn't exist on disk).

Comment: @Cory thanks but it doesnt work too i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in global.asax file in application start

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```